# Flutter : How to implement a callback

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, callback

**How to implement a callback return the error message?**

Login function from AuthService class:

```
static void login(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Submit function from Login class:

```
_submit() {
   // If fail to login then return the error message
   AuthService.login(_email, _password);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Future<AuthResult> login(String email, String password) async {
    try {
    Future<AuthResult> result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return result;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Then you can call the method like this:

```
_submit() {
   // If fail to login then return the error message
   login(_email, _password).then((result) => {
      print(result);
  });
}
```

The method `signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns `Future<AuthResult>`, therefore assign it to that type, the `await` keyword will wait until the method finishes execution and then it will return the value of type `Future<AuthResult>`.

> A future represents the result of an asynchronous operation, and can have two states: uncompleted or completed.

When you call the method `login()`, you can add the `then()` method which registers callbacks to be called when this future completes.

> When this future completes with a value, the onValue callback will be called with that value.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Future/then.html

Answer (score 1):

```
  // wrapping the firebase calls
  Future<FirebaseUser> loginUser({String email, String password}) {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  }
```

the user info is returned, you not sure what you need the callback for?

```
 userInfo = await AuthService().loginUser(email: _email, password: _password);
```